# Ansible: Handling temporary file idempotently and securely

Tags: ansible, temporary-files

In Ansible (RHEL 8 if it matters), I need to create a temporary file from a template with sensitive content. After a few other tasks are completed, it should be deleted. The temporary file is an answerfile for an installer that will run as a command. The installer needs a user name and password.

I can't figure out if there is a way to do this easily in Ansible.

The brute-force implementation of what I'm looking for would look similar to this:

```
- name: Create answer file
  template:
    src: answerfile.xml.j2
    dest: /somewhere/answer.xml
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode:  '0600'

- name: Install
  command: /somewhere/myinstaller --answerfile /somewhere/answer.xml
  creates: /somewhereelse/installedprogram

- name: Delete answerfile
  file:
    path: /somewhere/answer.xml
    state: absent
```

Of course, this code is not idempotent - the answer file would get created and destroyed on each run.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe Ansible vault is an option here?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Thank you for your suggestion! Ansible vault does something different. It provides a secure way to store the value of variables. So vault could be the source of the password. But it does not do anything about situations where a file needs to be stored on the target host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test the existence of the file. If it exists skip the block. For example

```yaml
- stat:
    path: /somewhereelse/installedprogram
  register: st

- block:

    - name: Create answer file
      template:
        src: answerfile.xml.j2
        dest: /somewhere/answer.xml
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode:  '0600'

    - name: Install
      command: /somewhere/myinstaller --answerfile /somewhere/answer.xml

    - name: Delete answerfile
      file:
        path: /somewhere/answer.xml
        state: absent

  when: not st.stat.exists
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

Taking the task "Delete answerfile" out of the block will make the code more secure. It will always make sure the credentials are not stored in the file. The task won't fail if the file is not present.

```yaml
- stat:
    path: /somewhereelse/installedprogram
  register: st

- block:

    - name: Create answer file
      template:
        src: answerfile.xml.j2
        dest: /somewhere/answer.xml
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode:  '0600'

    - name: Install
      command: /somewhere/myinstaller --answerfile /somewhere/answer.xml

  when: not st.stat.exists

- name: Delete answerfile
  file:
    path: /somewhere/answer.xml
    state: absent
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Comment: Ah, nice solution. I didn't know about `block` (I'm new to Ansible).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. And thanks for the extra remark about deleting the answerfile!

Comment: One side effect to be aware of: when using block this way, the tasks inside the block will not show up as "unchanged" but will not appear at all in the run. That is probably fine in most cases. The alternative is to attach the when... condition to each task individually. In that case, each task would show up as skipped.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this solution potentially represents a *slight* improvement on your solution.

With this solution the tasks which create and delete the answerfile will be skipped (rather than always run and reporting changed) if the program you're targeting is already installed.

I still don't love this solution as I don't really like skips.

```yaml
# Try call the installedprogram. --version is arbitrary here.
# --help, or a simple `which installedprogram` could be alternatives.
- name: Try run installedprogram
  command: '/somewhereelse/installedprogram --version'
  register: installedprogram_exists
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: False

# Only create answer file if installedprogram is not installed
- name: Create answer file
  template:
    src: answerfile.xml.j2
    dest: /somewhere/answer.xml
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode:  '0600'
  when: installedprogram_exists.rc != 0

- name: Install
  command: /somewhere/myinstaller --answerfile /somewhere/answer.xml
  creates: /somewhereelse/installedprogram

# Only delete answer file if installedprogram is not installed
- name: Delete answerfile
  file:
    path: /somewhere/answer.xml
    state: absent
  when: installedprogram_exists.rc != 0
```